# "All joins can be rewritten to sub queries", is this statement true?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I wonder if there any case that a join can not be converted to a sub-query.

BTW: I am not discussing advantages and disadvantage of using sub-query or using join.

Comment: For any one-to-many relationship a join between two tables will return something different than a sub-query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e50d9/1  So I would say the answer is a clear: "No, that statement is **not** true"

Comment: However you can change that around so that you aren't selecting from the parent but rather the child. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e50d9/4/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, a `JOIN [INNER JOIN]`, from the theoretical point of view, is a projection of a `CROSS JOIN` (every combination of two tables). If you can get a cross join using a subquery and apply any function on it, then you have a perfect substitute. I think you can always transform:

```
SELECT T1.A, T2.B
FROM T1
JOIN T2
ON condition(T1.C, T2.D)
```

into:

```
SELECT T1.A, T2.B
FROM T1
WHERE condition(T1.C, ALL(SELECT T2.D FROM T2))
```

A similar conclusion can be reached with `LEFT [OUTER] JOINS` and `RIGHT [OUTER] JOINS` (the other types supported on MySQL), by including the NULL value:

```
SELECT T1.A, T2.B
FROM T1
WHERE condition(T1.C, ALL(SELECT T2.D FROM T2) UNION SELECT NULL)
```

Comment: I would like to comment that asking what is theoretically possible is not very useful. In reality, while there are some queries that can be written as a JOIN or as a SUBQUERY with identical performance (more and more as the query optimiser becomes better), in many cases only one of them is practical and/or performant, and there are subqueries that cannot be expressed as joins.

Comment: agree. But this question is all about theoretical possibility.

Comment: @zx_wing yes, that is why I answered theoretically and tried to demonstrate it, but I wanted to write an addendum for other viewers.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the statement is **false**, though it's difficult to prove a negative.

I don't believe a `CROSS JOIN` could be done with sub queries

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2
```

or for that matter any join that delivers a many to many result

Comment: Well, I can do a cross join like this: `SELECT c , (SELECT i FROM t2 LIMIT 1) as i FROM t1 UNION SELECT c , (SELECT i FROM t2 LIMIT 1, 1) as i FROM t1 UNION SELECT c, (SELECT i FROM t2 LIMIT 2, 1) FROM t1 ...;`

Comment: I concede, that is true.  I wouldn't want to be the one to generate it though :)